# Is it possible to create an infinite sequence in which no subsequence is repeated 3 times in a row?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorics-on-words, chess

In Chess, there is the [Threefold Repetition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_repetition) where if a sequence of moves is repeated 3 times in a row, either player can claim a draw.

Say two players wanted to play a legal, infinite game of chess. How would they decide on a series of moves that never violates the threefold repetition criteria? Alternately, can it be proved that all infinite sequences (with finite alphabets) must eventually satisfy the threefold repetition criteria? If so, is it possible to know what the maximum number of moves possible in a game would be without either playing being able to claim a draw?

Comment: Aside from other issues, the Threefold Repetition Rule described in this post bears very little resemblance to the Threefold Repetition Rule from the actual game of chess.

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077472364

Comment: I don't see why this was closed unless people feel the op already new the answer.  This question was asked and answered by Morse-Hedlund in the 40s

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence#History

Comment: The [Kolakoski sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence) is another example.

Comment: This is not a mathematical comment but a chess one (and Steven Landsburg has already hinted at this): the opening post misunderstands and misquotes the threefold repetition rule in chess. A player can claim a draw if the same POSITION occurs three times, the sequence of moves if irrelevant (it says just as much on the linked page). As there are only finitely many possible positions, there are only finitely many games that avoid a triple repetition. The mathematical question asked thus has nothing to do with the chess one.

Comment: Furthermore, to be a bit pedantic, there is nothing "illegal" about a triple repetition in chess, it's simply that any of the player can claim a draw, but they can also both decide to play on.

Answer (score 7):

For the question in the title, you're looking for [cube-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word#Related_concepts) infinite words.  Of special interest are cube-free infinite words that are binary (use an alphabet of two letters).  A lot of work has been done on these.  (For example, search for questions here with the [combinatorics-on-words](/questions/tagged/combinatorics-on-words) tag.)

For the question specific to chess, see https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4113/3489.